# Azure DevOps Build error NETSDK1005: Assets file doesn't have a target for net7.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, .net-7.0

I have created new project using template `ASP.NET Core Web API` in Visual Studio 2022. This is simple API project and have not change anything in the template except in `program.cs'; moved out swagger outside the` if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())`so that I can use swagger when deploy application in`Azure App Service'

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

I am using Azure DevOps and getting build error which I need to resolve

`error`

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Web.APIs\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

[image]

In `project.assets.json` file, I can see `TargetFrameworks` is set to `7.0`

[image]

not really sure, what I am missing from the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1005), the NuGet version should be higher than 5.8.
We got the same error too. What we did was

- Add a NuGet Installer task as a previous step to NuGet restore (already included if you are using the classic editor in DevOps to define the pipeline).
- In the task, you can mention the version of NuGet, which we mentioned as 5.8

[image: pipeline task screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Ajay, I had this problem as well and your answer resolved it.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for the support, it did work for me